# DAX cannot compute a FILTER with "not equals" comparison

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a single column with 400K rows, which contain random numbers.

The following DAX formula calculates immediately, but the inverse (just negating the equals condition) results in an Out Of Memory Exception (after the calculation runs for several minutes). Can you reproduce it and how to solve it? Thanks.

```
test_filter_1 = COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
             table_1,
             table_1[column1] = EARLIER(table_1[column1])
     )
)


test_filter_1_negated = COUNTROWS(
           FILTER(
                   table_1,
                   NOT(table_1[column1] = EARLIER(table_1[column1]))
             )
  )
```

Comment: Is it any better using `<>` (not equal) instead of the `NOT()` operator?

Comment: No - it is the same with `<>`. I just posted the version with `NOT()`, because it illustrates better the strange behavior that just negating the result of the `=` is also causing the issue.

Comment: I have constructed a single column table with 400k rows, each populated with a random integer 1-100.  Both the 'equal' calculated column and the 'not equal' calculated column as you have shown them build for me.  How wide are the tables you are using (how many columns)  How much memory is on your machine?

Comment: I would suggest using DAX Studio to see what the query is doing performance wise

Comment: @RyanB. It builds with integers between 1 and 100 indeed. However if you increase the number of distinct values - for example between 1 and 10K - the issue is the same. Apparently it depends on the number of distinct values in the column as well.